# Use Storybook date control to edit Luxon DateTime object values

Tags: angular, typescript, testing, storybook, luxon

Storybook supports a ["date" control type with nice datepicker](https://storybook.js.org/docs/angular/essentials/controls#annotation) that supports string values.

In an app we use the [Luxon date / time library](https://moment.github.io/luxon/). For an Angular component, I tried to find a way to use the nice Storybook date time picker control for a component's input that expects a Luxon `DateTime` object.

I thought that there might be a way to define a value mapping for Storybook Controls, such that the Luxon object is converted to a date string (and back) for the Storybook control to handle. But I didn't find such a possibility, I thought that the [argTypes](https://storybook.js.org/docs/angular/api/argtypes) might support such a feature.

Is there a way to define a nice control for a Luxon object in Storybook?